# Magento error in backend when i enter the categories page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Im using Magento 1.9.0 and when i enter the backend 'Categories' page in my admin panel i get the following error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Source model "megamenu/menutype" not found for attribute "menutype"

Trace:
#0 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#8 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#11 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout))
#14 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#19 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#20 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#21 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#22 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#23 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#24 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#25 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#26 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#27 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 /mnt/waxvolume1/dev_architectural/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}
```

I was trying to transfer from one template to another i did this on a Development website in case i got errors such as this one and it seems like it was the correct decisions but i don't know how to get rid of this apparently from researching on google it suggests i delete some 'eav_attribute' records in the database i don't even know where to start. I think its my new theme conflicting with my old one.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Thank you if its in the wrong section my mistake i will post it in the correct location.